# how to open multiple windows

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'd like to open a new Window whenever a button is clicked. As shown in the picture, I would like to open a new **Popup Window** when the **Button** is pressed.

However, I can currently open **ONLY ONE** window whenever I click the button.

Any idea?

[image]

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    lazy var myNewWindowController: newWindowController? =
    {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var newWC = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("new")  as? newWindowController
        return newWC
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func showWindow(sender: NSButton) {
        myNewWindowController?.showWindow(self)
    } 
}
```

Just like Notes. Whenever I select an object, it will pop up another window for editing.

[image]